# Is it possible to map without releasing key in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

I want to make such an instruction

```
nmap <leader>w  <Plug>WordMotion_w
```

worked not only when I press <leader> + "w" at the same time but also when I hold down <leader> and press "w" several times. Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps you need pending operator?  try :help omap-info

Comment: If Neovim didn't change its input queue then from Vim's, then it is not possible to do that natively.